# how to connect aws secret manager using spring boot application without aws acceskey and secretkey

Tags: spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

Deployed in aws kubernate cluster getting exception# unable to load AWS credential exception.

I tried secretmanager API code but got failed. Expecting to get secrets from secret manager without aws accesskey and secret key.some one please provide best possible solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible without AWS AccesskeyId and SecretAccessKey

**AWS Java SDK v1.x**

Add dependency in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.347</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
@Configuration
public class AwsSecretManagerConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public AWSSecretsManager awsSecretsManager(){
        return AWSSecretsManagerClient
                .builder()
                .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
                .withRegion("AWS_REGION")
                .build();
    }
}
```

**AWS Java SDK v2.x**

Add dependency in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.23</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
@Configuration
public class AwsSecretManagerConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecretsManagerClient secretsManagerClient(){
        return SecretsManagerClient
                .builder()
                .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
                .region(Region.of("AWS_REGION"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit for giving the answer. I used AWS JDK 1.x version of code but still getting same error## Unable to load AWS credential exception from container expecting AccesskeyId and SecretAccessKey.

Comment: Ok, Can you please check if beans are loaded properly?